# Remove the Parent Node based on Child condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need help here to remove the xml node based on some condition

Here is my xml

> ```
> <result>
> <product>
> <auto>
>   <report>
>     <auto>
>       <admin></admin>
>       <report>
>         <search>
>           <subjects>
>             <subject>
>               <name>
>                 <first>John</first>
>                 <last>D</last>
>               </name>
>             </subject>
>           </subjects>
>         </search>
>       </report>
>     </auto>
>   </report>
> </auto>
> <auto>
>   <report>
>     <auto>
>       <admin></admin>
>       <report>
>         <search>
>           <subjects>
>             <subject>
>               <name>
>                 <first>Jack</first>
>                 <last>L</last>
>               </name>
>             </subject>
>           </subjects>
>         </search>
>       </report>
>     </auto>
>   </report>
> </auto>
> </product>
> </result>
> ```

Out of this xml, based on first and last name, remove the rest of "auto" node

Keep "auto" node if First name = John and Last name = D

Expected xml:

> ```
> <result>
> <product>
> <auto>
>   <report>
>     <auto>
>       <admin></admin>
>       <report>
>         <search>
>           <subjects>
>             <subject>
>               <name>
>                 <first>John</first>
>                 <last>D</last>
>               </name>
>             </subject>
>           </subjects>
>         </search>
>       </report>
>     </auto>
>   </report>
> </auto>  
> </product>
> </result>
> ```

I am tring to extract the required content first by

> ```
>   var query =
>   from p in XDocument.Parse(myXml).Root.Elements   ("result/product/auto/report/auto/report/search/subjects/subject/name")
>   where (
>   from c in p.Elements("first")
>   where c.Value == "John"
>   select c
>   ).Any()
>   select p;
> ```
>
> Please suggest me here.

Comment: Linq is for _querying_, not _updating_.  You can either select all nodes that _don't_ match your criteria into a new XML structure, or you can use linq to find the nodes that _do_ match, loop through them, and remove them fron the original structure.  Either way, you need to show what you have now to see how (even if it doesn't work) you're planning to use Linq.

Comment: I am trying to extract the required xml first and then restructure it by adding root elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
    string first = "John";
    string last = "D";
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    xd.Root.Element("product").Elements("auto").ToList()
        .ForEach(x=>
            {
            var name = x.Descendants("name").First();
            if (name.Element("first").Value != first
                && name.Element("last").Value != last)
                x.Remove();
            });
    Console.WriteLine(xd);
```

Print:

```
<result>
  <product>
    <auto>
      <report>
        <auto>
          <admin></admin>
          <report>
            <search>
              <subjects>
                <subject>
                  <name>
                    <first>John</first>
                    <last>D</last>
                  </name>
                </subject>
              </subjects>
            </search>
          </report>
        </auto>
      </report>
    </auto>
  </product>
</result>
```

Link:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZZ2Hlr