# Remove element from XML based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, linq

Below is the XML structure I have.

XML

```
<Info>
<Details>
<ID>user</ID>
<StartDate>23-10-2016</StartDate>
<EndDate>22-10-2016</EndDate>
</Details>
<Details>
<ID>user1</ID>
<StartDate>23-10-2016</StartDate>
<EndDate>24-10-2016</EndDate>
</Details>
<Details>
<ID>user2</ID>
<StartDate>23-10-2016</StartDate>
<EndDate>22-11-2016</EndDate>
</Details>
</Info>
```

Now I need to compare the `EndDate` node with today's date. If EndDate is lesser than today's date, then I need to remove the whole `Details` parent node. For Ex: Let's assume `strDate` a string that has today's date.

The below code takes all the values of EndDate and now, how can I compare the string value and loop through xml elements and delete them.

```
 object[] arr = xDos.Descendants("Details").Elements("EndDate").
                Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

Now this whole portion should be deleted as of comparing with todays date.

```
<Details>
<ID>user</ID>
<StartDate>23-10-2016</StartDate>
<EndDate>22-10-2016</EndDate>
</Details>
```

Really appreciate any suggestions on this.

**Update 1:**

```
 XDocument xDos = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Info.xml"));
 XElement xDo = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Info.xml"));
 List<XElement> arr = xDo.Descendants("Details").Where(n => DateTime.ParseExact(n.Element("EndDate").Value + "", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Today.Date).ToList<XElement>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
            {
                XElement ele = arr[i];
                ele.Remove();
            }               
            xDos.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Info.xml"));
```

Comment: loop the arr which you got above and remove like this, @Learner just give a try.

doc.Descendants().Where(e => (string) e < "23-10-2016").Remove();

Comment: @Meena - I tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: then have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896485/remove-the-parent-node-based-on-child-condition

Comment: List<XElement> arr = xDos.Descendants("Details").Where(n => DateTime.ParseExact(n.Element("EndDate").Value + "", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.Today.Date).ToList<XElement>(); This will give you a list... then run following  for (int i = 0 ; i <arr.Count(); i++)
            {
                XElement ele = arr[i];
                ele.Remove();
            }

Comment: @Anand - It loops in and doesn't remove the values and moreover need to get less than todays date and it has to be lesser than.Any thoughts?

Comment: @Learner try this
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  
  xd.Element("Info").Element("Details").Elements("EndDate")
     .Where(x => (string)x != "23-10-2016")
     .Remove();

Comment: @Learner - You can change the sign to get it working... It removed elements for me ...

Comment: @Meena - This will work only for equality what s/he is interested in is; leas than/ greater than

Comment: List<XElement> arr = xDos.Descendants("Details").Where(n => DateTime.ParseExact(n.Element("EndDate").Value + "", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Today.Date).ToList<XElement>(); This will give you a list... then run following for (int i = 0 ; i <arr.Count(); i++) { XElement ele = arr[i]; ele.Remove(); }

Comment: @Anand - I have updated my post. Can you pls take a look?

Comment: xDos.Descendants("Details").ToList()
       .ForEach(x =>
       {
           if (DateTime.ParseExact(x.Element("EndDate").Value, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Today.Date)
               x.Remove();
       });

Comment: This should work...

Comment: @Anand - This worked. Can you post this as an answer, so I can mark it and upvote.